# Stop converting my answers to comments

Tags: discussion, comments

This is an aggravating feature, at least to me. For example, I was able to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588986/when-using-blur-does-chrome-suport-shadow/11589078) in one line, providing more than enough information. It was auto-converted to a comment (which does not accept markdown formatting so it was misstyled). For some questions, responding with "no" is a completely valid, correct, and informative answer. Now I have to pad my answers with unnecessary text to get around the convert-to-comment nonsense.

stop it

Comment: Fun fact: You can also pad your answers with *informative* text!

Comment: and it's still padding!! cool!!

Comment: Yeah. Padding that is actually useful for readers.

Answer (score 21):

> For some questions, responding with "no" is a completely valid, correct, and informative answer.

Hardly. If a question can be responded with a simple "no" and nothing else, it adds no value to Stack Overflow and should get closed rather than answered.

In any other case, there's some additional information that should accompany the "no", e.g, *why* the answer is "no" or what can be done about it.

Answer (score 14):

You may think you are double awesome for taking only one line for your answer (including the code!).

But you aren't. You should either have posted a comment detailing the possible duplicate, flagged for mod attention (because you don't have enough rep to cast a close vote), or....

... you could have quoted a relevant part from the target you linked to, as a way of explaining your answer. A terse bit of code followed by a link is not an answer with any value. If you have a link to a suitable answer but can't provide any more context then just leave the link as a comment.

Answer (score 11):

**No**

Comment: I would have +2 this if you had of included a full stop after the *No*, but a) I can only +1, and b) it would have made your answer 50% longer.

Comment: love the hypocrisy!